# Appending text to a FASTA accession number (using bash?)

Tags: bash, fasta

Could someone help me to come up with a strategy to edit my FASTA file, which has entries in the following format

```
sp|Q9NYW0|T2R10_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 10 OS=Homo sapiens 
sp|Q9NYV9|T2R13_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 13 OS=Homo sapiens
```

For each of these lines, I need to append the text "_REVERSED" to the accession number, which is between the ||. For example, the above entries would become:

```
sp|Q9NYW0_REVERSED|T2R10_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 10 OS=Homo sapiens 
sp|Q9NYV9_REVERSED|T2R13_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 13 OS=Homo sapiens
```

I know this is easy question, and think it could be accomplished using a sample bash script, but I am new to this and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do it with `awk`, but you can do it equally easy with `sed`, e.g.

```
$ sed 's/\(^[^|]*|\)\([^|]*\)\(.*$\)/\1\2_RESERVED\3/' yourfile
sp|Q9NYW0_RESERVED|T2R10_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 10 OS=Homo sapiens
sp|Q9NYV9_RESERVED|T2R13_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 13 OS=Homo sapiens
```

Essentially you are using 3 *back references* (e.g. those groups of characters captured between `\(...\)`) in the matching part of the normal *substitute* syntax, e.g.

```
sed 's/match/replace/'
```

In your case, the match is made up of the first back reference we wish to capture:

```
\(^[^|]*|\)   # match from beginning '^' everything not '|', with the '|'
```

that will be replaced put back in `replace` with the `\1` (first back reference). Next, we similarly gather the *accession number* with:

```
\([^|]*\)     # which just captures everything up to the next '|'
```

It will be inserted in `replace` as `\2_RESERVED` inserting the `"accession number + _RESERVED"` you are needing. Finally, we just collected everything else in the line with:

```
\(.*$\)       # which just says grab everything that remains '.*$'
```

Putting the full `replace` together as `\1\2_RESERVED\3`.

**Bash Solution**

If you need to do this in bash, then it can be done equally easily using a `IFS` (*Internal Field Separator*) set to `'|'` to split the fields and a simple `read` loop. For example:

```
$ while IFS=$'|' read a b c; do echo "${a}|${b}_RESERVED|${c}"; done <yourfile
sp|Q9NYW0_RESERVED|T2R10_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 10 OS=Homo sapiens
sp|Q9NYV9_RESERVED|T2R13_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 13 OS=Homo sapiens
```

Look over all the solutions and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

The regex solutions may be efficient, but hard to understand. One neat thing in awk is it naturally splits the input into fields, and [you can manipulate](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html) those fields before outputting them.  I find this easier to type/remember than a regex approach.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="|";OFS="|"} {$2=$2 "_REVERSED"}{print}' < t
sp|Q9NYW0_REVERSED|T2R10_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 10 OS=Homo sapiens
sp|Q9NYV9_REVERSED|T2R13_HUMAN Taste receptor type 2 member 13 OS=Homo sapiens
```